Did Dieudonné or Weyl ever comment on Archimedes?
If they were, in which book can I find that comment?

If Weil (instead of Weyl), see references into André Weil, Number Theory: An approach through history (Birkhauser, 1984)

One of the chapters in Dieudonné's book Mathematics - The Music of Reason is called Objects and Methods in Classical Mathematics and has a lot of commentary on Archimedes, his axiom, is spiral, his mechanical method for areas and volumes, etc.
